# How to Specify version of WebView Implementation to be used in Android App? Is there a way to package a version of "Android System WebView" in APK

Tags: android, react-native, webview, android-webview, react-native-webview

We have an Android Application built in React Native platform which loads a Web URL into a WebView. It imports the WebView component from the [react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) package. During runtime, we see that the Web URL is loaded on to the Android System WebView implementation available on the user's device. Due to some reason, our application performs poorly in the latest version of Android System WebView. It works good in an older version of the WebView.

Is there a way to specify the version of WebView Implementation that should be used in our App or bundle the specific version of WebView implementation within our APK which can be used to load the Web URL?